# Вкладное приложение aka Safari или MDI на Swift

Tags: swift

Недавно начал изучать Swift, до этого учил С# и вполне успешно. Так вот, в C# есть такая технология как MDI, когда мы можем запускать экземпляры окон в конкретном окне. На "шарике" это делается достаточно просто, а как это делается на Swift? Если говорить конкретно, то в целях обучения языка я хочу создать простую рисовалку, где каждый новый файл будет открываться в новой вкладке одного окна приложения.

Comment: MDI на iOS реализуется в виде отдельных ViewController

Comment: А можете показать как?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь, например: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5895-uikit-drawing-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app